# How to source a script code (set a variable) from another shell?

Tags: shell, freebsd, variable, csh

I tried to use FreeBSD.
The FreeBSD `root` user uses `csh` by default.

```
user@freebsd-13:~ $ echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
```

I know that setting a variable via `$()` does not work in `csh`.

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # export test=$(echo hello3)
Illegal variable name.
```

I want to do something like that

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh -c "export test=$(echo hello3)"
Illegal variable name.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
```

And it does not work either...
However, this works:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh -c "echo "hello""
hello
```

Or this works as well but in the scope of `sh`:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh
# export test=$(echo hello3)
# echo $test
hello3
# exit
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo $test
test: Undefined variable.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
```

Another attempt to set a variable via `sh`:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh -c "export test=`echo hello5`"
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo $test
test: Undefined variable.
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh -c "echo "$test""
test: Undefined variable.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
root@freebsd-13:~ # /bin/sh -c "export test=`echo hello3`"
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo $test
test: Undefined variable.
root@freebsd-13:~ # /bin/sh -c "echo "$test""
test: Undefined variable.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
```

Tried to source it:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # . sh -c "export test=$(echo hello3)"
Illegal variable name.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
root@freebsd-13:~ # . sh -c "export test=`echo hello3`"
.: Command not found.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
root@freebsd-13:~ # source sh -c "export test=`echo hello3`"
sh: No such file or directory.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
root@freebsd-13:~ # source /bin/sh -c "export test=`echo hello3`"
Unmatched '"'.
root@freebsd-13:~ # source /bin/sh -c "export test=$(echo hello3)"
Illegal variable name.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
root@freebsd-13:~ # source /bin/sh -c "export test="$(echo hello3)""
Illegal variable name.
root@freebsd-13:~ #
```

How should it be done properly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137198/discussion-on-question-by-t7e-how-to-source-a-script-code-set-a-variable-from).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm answering my question.
First of all the `source` command is used with files only.
If I want to run the code the way I described, I need to use `eval`.
Got a very clear explanation here: 
[How to source some shell code not a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706712/how-to-source-some-shell-code-not-a-file/706716#706716)

The crucial point for my understanding was that shebang line is ignored while sourcing, since the file isn't being executed: only its contents are.

So, the problem here is that to export a variable I need to run it in the current shell. And this current shell ignores any shebangs while sourcing, moreover, if I run `sh -c` - I run the code in a subshell.

`csh` does not support `sh` syntax. So, the only possible way to export a variable while using `csh` is to use its syntax.

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # setenv test `echo "hello world"`
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo $test
hello world
```

There are some other workarounds which are similar to those described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710790/how-to-source-a-csh-script-in-bash-to-set-the-environment

(but I need vice versa - source a bash script in a csh environment)